# Match character or end of line with sed

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

Trying to clean a `PYTHONPATH` variable which has the common syntax:

```
/a/path:/another/path/:/one/more/path
```

I want to remove all paths starting with `/mnt`. First try with `sed`:

```
sed 's,/mnt/[^:]\+:,,g' <<< $PYTHONPATH
```

It removes all occurences that start with `/mnt/`, following by one or more characters except colon, and the succeeding colon character.

This, however, will fail for the following example:

```
PYTHONPATH="/mnt/first/path:/mnt/second/path"
```

because the second path does not end with a colon. I couldn't give birth to anything better than running another search with the slightly different condition:

```
sed 's,/mnt/[^:]\+:,,g;s,/mnt/.*$,,g' <<< $PYTHONPATH
```

So now, after all occurences ending with a colon are removed, another run removes all occurences (in fact, there is at most one) that start with `/mnt/` and end with end of the string.

Questions:

1. For the task, is this an acceptable solution?
2. Is there a special case where the solution above will fail?
3. Is a single search solution possible here? Just curious.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Argonauts, you can do that in one line with the OR statement. You don't necessarily have to use the `-r` option, but the `sed` command will be a little bit more complex, since you have to escape the parentheses and bar as follow:

```
sed 's,/mnt/[^:]\+\(:\|$\),,g' <<< "$PYTHONPATH"
```

Notice that it is a good practice to quote variables in bash.

Comment: This didn't work for me on MacOS. Got around it by installing and using GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is acceptable, but an even easier, lazier way out is:

### Just make a new variable

```
NEWVAR="${PYTHONPATH}:"
sed 's,/mnt/[^:]\+:,,g' <<< $NEWVAR
```

Assuming you are assigning this to a variable, and want the added colon trimmed again, with bash variable manipulation you can do this:

```
newvar="${PYTHONPATH}:"
nomnt=$( sed 's,/mnt/[^:]\+:,,g' <<< $newvar )
nomnt=${nomnt%%:}
echo ${nomnt}
```

Or in all sed:

```
sed 's,/mnt/[^:]\+:,,g;s/:$//;' <<< "${PYTHONPATH}:"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extended regular expressions with sed to simplify things a little bit:

```
sed -r 's,/mnt/[^:]+(:|$),,g' <<< $PYTHONPATH
```

The `-r` indicates the use of an extended regex, which in this case is the OR statement `(:|$)`, causing it to end the pattern match on either a colon or end of line.

Note: with OS X and BSD versions of sed use `-E` instead of `-r`

And while it's likely blindingly obvious, if you are trying to update PYTHONPATH itself you need to assign the value after removing the /mnt/* entries:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(sed -r 's,/mnt/[^:]+(:|$),,g' <<< $PYTHONPATH)
```